# does pusher store persistent historical data in its channels?

Tags: pusher

Pusher seems like a good service but I was wondering if anyone knows if it can be used as a persistent activity stream.  For instance I would like to subscribe to a channel and get historical activity rather than just the new real-time activity events after I've subscribed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Channel event history is on our (Pusher's) backlog. You can keep track of updates here:
http://pusher.tenderapp.com/discussions/requests/30-event-history

Since we generally recommend publishing data from your server (for security reasons) this also gives you the opportunity to persist messages and provide your own channel history.

We do understand the benefits of event history which is why it's on our backlog.

Comment: It was on the page for over a year, the discussion is now closed since July, is there move on this topic ? This is very important feature and I'd be happy to work with it

Comment: You'd best ask this question via Pusher support.

Comment: https://support.pusher.com/hc/en-us/articles/202054413-What-happens-to-my-events-if-no-clients-are-subscribed-